# JNEAT - iterator.next() object contains 0s

Tags: java

So I'm using a library called JNEAT. It is pretty old around (from 2002).

Here is where the problem lies:

I use this library to evolve a set of neural networks. I use these neural nets to control something in a simulation. At the end of the simulation, I determine how well the neural net performed with a "fitness" value. I then assign this fitness to an object called Organism.

The issue is that the JNEAT thinks that the fitness is always zero. However I know that the object I pass in contains the actual fitness.

Here are some code snippets:

This is where I set the organisms with the new fitnesses. In this, the output is exactly as I expect it should be. Meaning that the fitnesses are correctly printed.

```
public void setOrganisms(Vector<Organism> organisms) {
     this.organisms = organisms;
     for(int i = 0; i < organisms.size(); i++)
     {
         System.out.printf("Organism %d fitness: %f\n", i, organisms.get(i).fitness);
     }
  }
```

****HOWEVER******

Here is where the species and organisms are initialized:

```
/** A Population is a group of Organisms including their species */
    public class Population extends Neat {
   /** The organisms in the Population */
      public Vector<Organism> organisms;

   /** Species in the Population the species should comprise all the genomes */
      public Vector<Species> species;

   /** For holding the genetic innovations of the newest generation */
      Vector<Innovation> innovations = new Vector<Innovation>(1,0);
```

This is the first time the fitnesses are used in the evolution function:

```
public void epoch(int generation) 
      {

         Iterator<Species> itr_specie;
         Iterator<Organism> itr_organism;
         double total = 0.0;
      //double total_expected=0.0;
         int orgcount = 0;
         int max_expected;
         int total_expected; //precision checking
         int final_expected;
         int half_pop = 0;
         double overall_average = 0.0;
         int total_organisms = 0;
         double tmpd = 0.0;
         double skim = 0.0;
         int tmpi = 0;
         int best_species_num = 0;
         int stolen_babies = 0;
         int one_fifth_stolen = 0;
         int one_tenth_stolen = 0;
         int size_of_curr_specie = 0;
         int NUM_STOLEN = Neat.p_babies_stolen; //Number of babies to steal
      // al momento NUM_STOLEN=1

         Species _specie = null;
         Species curspecies = null;
         Species best_specie = null;
         Vector<Species> sorted_species = null;


      // Use Species' ages to modify the objective fitness of organisms
      // in other words, make it more fair for younger species
      // so they have a chance to take hold
      // Also penalize stagnant species
      // Then adjust the fitness using the species size to "share" fitness
      // within a species.
      // Then, within each Species, mark for death 
      // those below survival_thresh * average


         itr_specie = species.iterator();
         while (itr_specie.hasNext()) 
         {
            _specie = ((Species) itr_specie.next());
            _specie.adjust_fitness();
         }

      //Go through the organisms and add up their fitnesses to compute the
      //overall average

         itr_organism = organisms.iterator();
         total = 0.0;
         while (itr_organism.hasNext()) 
         {
            Organism _organism = ((Organism) itr_organism.next());
            System.out.println(_organism.fitness);
            total += _organism.fitness;
         }


         total_organisms = organisms.size();
         overall_average = total / total_organisms;

         System.out.println(overall_average);

    }
```

Each of those println's prints out 0.0 to the console. I believe that this is related to the Iterator because organism itself returns 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code posting is incomplete: where are `species` and `organisms` initialized? And how does the first code block relate to the second?

Comment: I updated so that it is ore understandable. basically it works in that first section but not in the second one.

Comment: In your update you define them as `Vector` but do not initialize them, this however would result in a `NullPointerException` when you call `species.iterator()` or `organisms.iterator()`

Comment: 'organsims' is initialized in the constructor like: 'organisms = new Vector(size)'. I did not get any null pointer exceptions when running this.

Comment: In that case there are no elements in the vector, so you never iterate through them. What is your output? I guess you do not get anything from `System.out.println(_organism.fitness)` but only from `System.out.println(overall_average)`

Comment: No that is the weird part. It is 30 0.0's